# JOptionPane YES_NO_OPTION

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, conditional-statements, joptionpane

I'm having some problems with a very basic, beginner level Java program. I have a function which should return a value dependent on a user's response to a JOptionPane YES_NO_OPTION message box. The program runs just fine until you are presented with the option of starting again, or of backing out. No matter which option you choose, yes, or no, it takes you back to do a new loop. I know one way to fix this would simply be to rely on a cancel button, but I want to understand why this code isn't returning the values I expect it to, so would be very grateful for your help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class HelloMK2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            double Int1 = optiontakeshape();
            double Int2 = optiontakediam();
            if (Int1 == 1.0) {
                Shape s1 = new Circle(Int2);
                infoBox(s1.area2d());
            } else {
                Shape s1 = new Sphere(Int2);
                infoBox(s1.volume());
            }
            int yesno = repeat();
            if (yesno == 1) {
                System.out.println(yesno);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int repeat() {
        int j;
        int g = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to begin again?",
                "Repeat?", g);
        if (g == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            j = 1;
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (g == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            j = 2;
        } else {
            j = 3;
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println(j);
        return j;
    }
    //...
}
```

**EDIT:** Thank you for the many swift responses. I wasn't actually testing the value of the Yes/No result. The code I have now implemented is:

```
public static int repeat ()
        {
        int j;
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to begin again?", "Repeat?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            j = 2;
        } else {
            j = 1;
            //System.exit(0); escaped so I could test the break point was working properly
        }
        System.out.println(j);
        return j;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you testing what g is after you set it to JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem.

```
int g = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
```

`g` will always be `YES_NO_OPTION`, which in in terms of integer values is the same as `YES_OPTION`. Both are 0.

Instead try this

```
int g =  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to begin again?", "Repeat?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Comment: Don't believe, be [sure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, now I'm _sure_ :)

Answer (score 2):

Assign the selected value to `g`:

```
g = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to begin again?",
                "Repeat?", g);
```

Currently, g is given the value of `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;`

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing result of

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to begin again?",
                "Repeat?", g);
```

anywhere. You are just using value of `g` which is always equal to `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;` which is constant set to `0`.

Try maybe with this code.

```
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to begin again?",
        "Repeat?", g);
if ( response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    j = 1;
    System.exit(0);
} else if ( response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    j = 2;
} else {
    j = 3;
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Or maybe even better (and definitely shorter)

```
        //...
        if (repeat() == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("goodbye world");
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static int repeat() {
    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to begin again?",
            "Repeat?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way.

```
 if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == 0){
        System.out.println("YES");
 //The value zero represents index of first option which will be the YES option
    }
else if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == 1){
        System.out.println("NO");
 //The value one represents index of second option which will be the NO option
    }
```

You can remove the index number and replace with the format you have so that it reads like this:

```
if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        System.out.println("YES");
 option
    }
else if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        System.out.println("NO");
 option
    }
```

You can visit this YouTube link for more help [JOptionPane Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3NTQTOTNBM)